# IntelliJ does not recompile/build maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am running into problems when using IntelliJ for Spring development. At first, the IntelliJ `build` command works fine and picks up changes I make to the source code. At some point, this stops working and I can only compile my sources through maven, as the `build` or `rebuild project` commands seem to do nothing anymore.

I am confused, as it works as desired at the start but then stops working at some point.

**Steps to recreate**:

- Create a new Spring project using Spring Initializr:

  `curl https://start.spring.io/starter.zip -d type=maven-project -d javaVersion=11 -o demo.zip && unzip demo.zip`
- Start IntelliJ from the command line in that folder, this will auto-import the project: `idea64 .`
- Write a log message in the main class and run the project using `Run->Run 'DemoApplication'`. This compiles the sources to the `target` folder and starts up the project. You should see the log message
- Alter the log message, run again and the changes should be visible (*so far so good*)
- Now re-compile the sources via maven command `mvn compile` and restart IntelliJ
- From now on, running `build` or `rebuild project` within IntelliJ will not pick up any changes I make to any of my source files. In fact both commands don't seem to do anything at all. I have to compile via maven in order to properly compile my sources

I tried a few things to overcome this problem, but without success:

- Invalidated caches/restart
- Checked `project settings` for `Project Compiler Output` and set it to `<project-folder>/target`
- Checked `project settings/modules` for `output path` and `test output path` and put in the path as above
- Used `Reimport All Maven Projects`
- Deleted the `.idea` folder within the project folder. This seems to work, but is very inconvenient and surely no intended behavior. Also it breaks again if I recreate the steps detailed above.

Is anyone experiencing similar problems and/or has a solution?

Comment: Did you set everything up in the module settings? Right click your project --> Open Module settings. There you have to set the SDK and such.

Comment: First does your build work properly on plain command line ...furthermore Spring support needs Ultimate Edition ?

Comment: Are there any related errors or exceptions in idea.log and build.log? See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519. Enable debug logging for build.log file and inspect the file after reproducing the issue. Is there anything suspicious? Any plug-ins installed that may affect it? For example, see https://twitter.com/tagir_valeev/status/1260040670070407171 for somewhat related issue. I'd recommend reporting a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with all the details for the faster turnaround and convenience.

Comment: @ValentinGrégoire SDK is set up properly for the project. The `run` command can be used to run pre-compiled classes but it will not pick up any changes I make to any of my classes.

Comment: @khmarbaise How would I build from the command line? Are you referring to the mvn commands? if so, yes that works properly. I know that Spring support is a Ultimate feature, but why would the IDE behavior change between sessions? It works just as expected on the first start and only stops working after running a maven build lifecycle command and restarting the IDE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So for anyone running into the problems I described above:

Apparently deleting the `.idea` folder and restarting IntelliJ does indeed do the trick. The folder is recreated on restart and afterwards I'm able to switch between compiling within IntelliJ using `run`, `build` or `rebuild project` and compiling through maven goals (`mvn compile`, `mvn test`, `mvn surefire:test`, ...). This persists through restarts of IntelliJ such that I don't have to repeat this everytime I open a project.

I still don't know why this behavior happens, but it's a solution I'm happy to work with as long as I only have to do it every now and then for a project.

Comment: For me, modulex.xml inside .idea folder had wrong path to the .iml (module file). This happened probably during the import from Eclipse.

Comment: I confirm that this is indeed the cure. You don't have to delete the entire .idea directory, because if you do that then you lose settings for code style, scopes, copyright notices, spell checking dictionaries, inspections, and anything you might have shelved.  As a matter of fact, it is good practice to keep the .idea directory in source control so as to never lose those. But to refresh intellij, you can delete things like compiler.xml, encodings.xml, jarRepositories.xml, misc.xml, modules.xml and workspace.xml

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like do don't want Intellij's default build. You want Intellij to forward the build command to mvn. I assume this because you do not mention this step in your question.

Here's a screenshot that shows how to enable it:

[image: delegate build and rebuild to mvn]

More detail is available in the Intellij documentation https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#delegate_run_action

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I understood the entire problem. For me saving the files via `Ctrl+S` and then simply stopping/restarting the server didn't make the changes appear in the webapp until I opened the Project Settings -> Artifacts -> `*.war/ear: exploded` -> check "Include in project build".

[image]

Before that, I had to manually execute clean + package in the Maven tab, which is slow.